# Defining a integral of multi variable function as a second function python

Tags: python, function, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

## Defining a integral of multi variable function as a second function python

I am using python to integrate a multivariable function over only one of the variables (it is a function of x and theta and I am integrating over theta from 0 to 2*pi, hence the result is a function of x). I have attempted the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as inte
d=10.0
xvals=np.linspace(-d,d,1000)
def aIntegrand(theta,x):
    return 1/(2*np.pi)*np.sin(2*np.pi*x*np.sin(theta)/d)**2
def A(x):
    return (inte.quad(aIntegrand,0,2*np.pi,args=(x,))[0])**(1/2)

plt.plot(xvals,A(xvals))
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("A(x)")
plt.show()
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I assume this is because the result of the quad integrator is an array with two elements and python doesn't like defining the function based on an indexed array? That is a complete guess of the problem though. If anyone knows how I can fix this and could let me know, that'd be great :)

---

## A second attempt

I have managed to get the plot of the integral successfully using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as inte
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d=10.0
xvals=np.linspace(-d,d,1000)
thetavals=np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,1000)
def aIntegrand(theta,x):
    return 1/(2*np.pi)*np.sin(2*np.pi*x*np.sin(theta)/d)**2
def A(x):
    result=np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i]=(inte.quad(aIntegrand,0,2*np.pi,args=(x[i],))[0])**(1/2)
    return result
def f(x,theta):
    return x**2* np.sin(theta)

plt.plot(xvals,A(xvals))
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("A(x)")
plt.show()
```

[image: Integral Plot]

But this does not give A(x) as a function, due to the way I have defined it, it requires an array form input. I need the function to be of the same form as aIntegrand, where when given parameters returns a single value & so the function can be integrated repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that what you seek exists within Scipy. However, you have at least two alternatives.

1. First, you can create an interpolator using [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d). This means that the range of x values you initially give determines the range for which you will be able to call the interpolator. This interpolator can then be called for any value of x in this interval.
2. You can perform the second integral even though you do not have a callable. The function [simps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) only requires values and their location to provide an estimate of the integration process. Otherwise, you can perform the double integration in one call with [dblquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad).

Answer (score 1):

First note that your integral can be calculated analytically. It is

```
0.5 * (1 - J0(4 * pi * x / d))
```

where `J0` is the Bessel function of the first kind.

Second, you could use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (one of my projects); it has fully vectorized computation.

```py
import numpy as np
import quadpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special

d = 10.0
x = np.linspace(-d, d, 1000)


def aIntegrand(theta):
    return (
        1
        / (2 * np.pi)
        * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.multiply.outer(x, np.sin(theta)) / d) ** 2
    )


Ax2, err = quadpy.quad(aIntegrand, 0, 2 * np.pi)
Ax = np.sqrt(Ax2)

plt.plot(x, Ax, label="quadpy")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("A(x)")
plt.plot(x, np.sqrt(0.5 * (1 - scipy.special.jv(0, 4*np.pi*x/d))), label="bessel")
# plt.show()
plt.savefig("out.png", transparent=True, bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image]